# getattr with two tuples after it

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, getattr

I am working with a code base which contains a line which I really can't understand:

```
x, x, z = getattr(ReceiveFile, maxsizes)(input, args)
```

So if it didn't have the second tuple at the end it would be just

```
x, y, z = ReceiveFile.maxsizes
```

How do I interpret that tuple at the end `(input, args)` ? I can't that easily run this code and play with a debugger to come to an understanding..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a string value for the `maxsizes` variable:

```
maxsizes = "abc"
```

the following

```
x, x, z = getattr(ReceiveFile, maxsizes)(input, args)
```

is equivalent to:

```
x, x, z = ReceiveFile.abc(input, args)
```

Or in words: The object `ReceiveFile` has a method with the name `maxsizes` (which is `ReceiveFile.abc`) which is called with the arguments `input` and `args`. The parentheses do not denote a `tuple`, but a function call.

Comment: hello, `maxsizes` is a method or an attirubute of the `ReceiveFile?. [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) or when we add a `(input, args)`, it interpreted as method? Thanks

Comment: @Aybars First of all, a method is an attribute. And `maxsizes` is the name of a method of `ReceiveFile`. Note that `maxsizes` is a variable, so that name is not necessarily `"maxsizes"`, but can be any eligible string really.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Aybars Cheers. There is no interpretation involved: first the attribute (without `()`) is looked up and an object returned. That object is then called via `(...)`. This either works or raises a TypeError, if the object is not callable.

Answer (score 3):

`getattr` is returning a function, which is then called with `input` and `args` as its arguments. The return value of that function is then unpacked into `x`, `y`, and `z`.

In longer form, it's the same as

```
f = getattr(ReceiveFile, maxsizes)
x, y, z = f(input, args)
```